# How to store new Object in JTextField input

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am creating a GUI for users to create a Menu from a selection of four combo boxes with Entrees, Sides, Salads, and Desserts. The "Create Menu" button prompts the user to input a menu name and store the new Menu object in the input. How can I store an object of type "Menu" that contains Entrees, Sides, Salads, and Desserts into this user input which is then stored in a JTextArea(My menuList variable)? I would also like to store the new menu name into the new menu object. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
        btnMenuInput = new JButton("Create New Menu");
        btnMenuInput.setBounds(120, 100, 200, 30);
        btnMenuInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
                Entree selectedEntree = (Entree)cboEntrees.getSelectedItem();
                Side selectedSide = (Side)cboSides.getSelectedItem();
                Salad selectedSalad = (Salad)cboSalads.getSelectedItem();
                Dessert selectedDessert = (Dessert)cboDesserts.getSelectedItem();

                Menu menu = new Menu("", selectedEntree, selectedSide, selectedSalad, selectedDessert);
                if(menuList.getText().length() == 0) {
                    menuList.setText(input.getText().toString());
                }
                else menuList.setText(menuList.getText() + "\n" + input.getText());
                childFrame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        childFrame.getContentPane().add(btnMenuInput);  
    }
});
```

Comment: Your question is a bit broad and may be closed for this, but it almost sounds like you're trying to store a menu object in a JTextField or JTextArea, and this you should not do. You will probably want to restructure your GUI in a M-V-C or Model-View-Controller way, so you can separate logical concerns from user-interface concerns. Then your text fields and text areas can display the state of the model, and can contribute into updating the model, but not be the model.

Comment: HoverCraft, It's for a college project using the program eclipse so I think MVC would be out of the question. I apologize if it's broad but I'm not sure how to condense it. When the user enters in the new menu name I want that input to be put in the JTextArea(which I've done), however, I'm unsure how when the user clicks the new menu created in the JTextArea that it can retrieve the new menu object that has stored the selected items from the combo boxes?

Comment: A JTextArea is not what you want if you want a collection of *selectable* text. Perhaps you want to instead use a JList. It can be a `JList<MyMenu>` one that holds your menu objects but displays a text representation, but its model holds the actual object of interest, and it can look just like a JtextArea if desired.